# One2Many Relation does not have base model with ID

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

We currently have the following schema;

```
type Reactions []*Reaction

type Post struct {
    ID string `pg:",pk" json:",omitempty"`
    CreatorID string `pg:",notnull"`
    Creator   *User  `pg:",rel:has-one,fk:creator_id"`
    Groups   Groups  
    Reactions Reactions `pg:",rel:has-many" json:",omitempty"`
}

type Reaction struct {
    ID string `pg:",pk" json:",omitempty"`

    Type ReactionType `pg:",notnull"`

    CreatorID string `pg:",notnull"`
    Creator   *User  `pg:",rel:has-one,fk:creator_id"`

    PostID string  `pg:",notnull"`
    Post   *Post `pg:",rel:has-one,fk:post_id"`
}
```

When trying to query all Posts including their Reaction Relations using the following query, we recieve the following error message; `pg: relation=\"Reactions\" does not have base model=Post with id=\"\" (check join conditions)`

```
func (pm PGPostRepo) selectQuery(model ...interface{}) *orm.Query {
    return pm.db.Model(model...).
        Relation("Creator.id").
        Relation("Creator.given_name").
        Relation("Creator.family_name").
        Relation("Reactions.type").
        Column("post.*")
        Where("post.id = ?", postID).
        Select()
}
```

I'm actually quite lost on this one, as if we replace
`Relation("Reaction.type")` with `Relation("Reaction.*")` we do not get the error(Though both `Creator` & `Post` are null), but then we're retrieving more columns than we'd like.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a pro but isn't it the Reactions in Post model. It should be `Reactions Reaction ...` instead of `Reactions Reactions ...`. Because the model is Reaction, not Reactions. I hope it solves the problem and i am not a stupid.

Comment: Hey! Yeah, sorry - I forgot to include that Reactions is simply `[]* Reaction`. It shouldn't have any effect on the query, and to confirm `Relation("Reaction.type")` complains about missing relation. :]